# CMake compiles executable before generating message libraries

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I face the problem that I get an compiling error while compiling something that is for example using a custom service. The error is that it can't find the headerfile or library that should be generated during catkin_make. If I compile it with one core (catkin_make -j1) it works fine. If it is compiled once the error does not occur again cause the library exists - till the next clean

I guess I defined something wrong in the CMakeList or is it a general problem?

Thanks in advance

Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217767/cmake-compiles-executable-before-generating-message-libraries/) by [chrisb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23915/chrisb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2015-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see the catkin documentation for instructions: http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/cpp_msg_dependencies.html

You are missing a dependency between your executable target and the message generation step.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chrisb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23915/chrisb/) on 2015-09-16**:
Thank you, I haven't had the dependency in one of my libraries, this line solved my problem:

> add_dependencies(your_**library**
> ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})